# Kindly suggest what would be the loop invariant in the following algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Kindly suggest what would be the loop invariant in the following algorithm ( I need it for the purpose of proving the partial correctness of the algorithm).

`MinDistance(A[0...n-1])
dmin <- ∞
for i = 0 to n-1 do
   for j= 0 to n-1 do
     if i ≠ j and |A[i] - A[j]| < dmin
       dmin <-|A[i] - A[j]|
return dmin`

another algorithm for which the loop invariant is to be discovered is

`MinDistance2(A[0...n-1])
dmin <- ∞
for i = 0 to n-2 do
    for j= i+1 to n-1 do
       temp <-|A[i] - A[j]| 
       if temp < dmin 
          dmin <- temp
return dmin`

Comment: The loop invariants state what dmin is at the start or end of each iteration. If you understand how the algorithms work, you should be able to come up with these invariants.

Comment: Thanks Yuval. I understood the concept of loop invariant but can you please help me in writing it in the style like- (i < n -2)  ∧ (∀k:0…..i-2, ∀m:k…..n-1  dmin < A[k] – A[m])

Comment: It's best if you did it on your own. It's the only way to learn anything.

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to learn here dear.

Comment: Perhaps you can let us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you tell, given an array A, what dmin is?

Comment: what i have tried so far is (i < n-1)  ∧ (∀k:0…..i-1, ∀m:k…..n-1  dmin < A[k] – A[m]).....not sure if that is right

Comment: dmin is the smallest distance between two elements of an array A.

Comment: for the second algorithm what i have tried is (i < n -2) ∧ (∀k:0…..i-2, ∀m:k…..n-1 dmin < A[k] – A[m]) and the one i mentioned earlier was for 1st algorithm. Kindly suggest guys, am i going right or wrong somewhere?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus- can you help